# Get Column name and index of an outlier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying investigate if my outliers are data errors or exceptional real data points. 
This is my code to find their column name and index number.

```
outliers = []
for r in df.index:
    for c in df.columns:
       if (df.loc[r,c]>0.6):
          outliers.append([r,c])
```

This code works but is inefficient. Is there a better way? The outlier cutoff value is `0.6`

Answer (score 1):

Numpy [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
np.argwhere(df.values>0.6)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10).reshape(2,5))
#          0         1         2         3         4
#0  0.002991  0.976504  0.683546  0.506011  0.207941
#1  0.500685  0.738651  0.962306  0.902494  0.791330

np.argwhere(df.values>0.6).tolist()
#[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

If you need not the index numbers (iloc), but the values of the row/col index, you can use:

```
[(df.index[x[0]], df.columns[x[1]]) for x in np.argwhere(df.values>0.6).tolist()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `stack` and boolean indexing:

Example df:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
```

---

```
thresh = 6 #change as required
s = df.stack(dropna=False)
print(s[s.gt(thresh)].index.tolist())


[(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (4, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (4, 'C')]
```

---

```
outliers = []
for r in df.index:
    for c in df.columns:
       if (df.loc[r,c]> thresh):
          outliers.append([r,c])
print(outliers)

[[1, 'A'], [1, 'B'], [2, 'C'], [3, 'A'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'A'], [4, 'B'], [4, 'C']]
```